# jQuery only working locally on Rails site

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I recently implemented a bunch of jQuery behavior on my personal site, and I also moved all of my JS into page-specific JS files (I had previously had all of the JS at the bottom of each respective page inside a script tag).  Everything worked fine locally, but when I pushed the site live nearly all of the jQuery animations stopped working.  They're mostly slide-in, slide-up etc., and before each element is animated on scroll I have it positioned off screen so now the site looks blank.

I know this question has been asked multiple times, but none of the previous answers remedied my issue.  I've tried multiple combinations of require rails_ujs, jquery, jquery_ujs etc. with no luck.  I'm currently getting the Reference Error: $ is not defined in the console (no luck with the S/O answers in that search either).

Any thoughts?

Here's the site link along with the application.js file, a custom JS file, and the HTML head.

www.justincefai.co

application.js file

```
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

custom JS file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $horizontal = $(".about-left");

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var s = $(this).scrollTop(),
      d = $(document).height(),
      c = $(this).height();

    scrollPercent = (s / (d - c)) * 6;

    var position = scrollPercent * ($(document).width() - $horizontal.width());

    $horizontal.css({
      right: "calc(82% - 150px + " + position + "px)"
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $horizontalR = $(".about-right");
  var $title = $(".about-top");

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var s = $(this).scrollTop(),
      d = $(document).height(),
      c = $(this).height();

    scrollPercent = (s / (d - c)) * 6;

    var position = scrollPercent * ($(document).width() - $horizontalR.width());

    $horizontalR.css({
      left: "calc(82% - 150px + " + position + "px)"
    });
  });
});
```

application.html.erb head tag

```
<head>
        <%= favicon_link_tag asset_path('favicon.png'), :rel => 'icon', :type =>  'image/png' %>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.9"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <title>Justin Cefai</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Justin Cefai is a software engineer specializing in full-stack development.  He has experience with Ruby, Rails, JavaScript, and building web applications.">

    </head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
...
})
```